# Overflow hidden, but still able to scroll (only Chrome)

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a very strange CSS "bug".

I'm currently working on an slider thing (slides have form elements on them). When I click & drag (to the right to scroll horizontal) on an label within the slide, then the `container` scrolls and the next slide comes visible while the property `overflow: hidden;` is set on the container.

I found out that the overflow property works normal when there is NO `label` tag present.

Does anyone has a solution herefor? I tried a lot of CSS stuff but no success. 
I recreated the bug in JsFiddle here: [clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/WJc3X/4/)

### Update

- The click & drag bug thing appears only in Chrome. (I tested IE and FF)
- Plus, it's **NOT** about the scroll bar of the `ul list` with the `labels`, but about the fact that you can click on an `label` and `drag` it to the right to scroll to the next slide.

Comment: Issue has been fixed by Google. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116655

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chromium (Google chrome is based on this) see: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116655

Because both Safari and Chrome appear to show the issue I would hazard a guess that this bug is general to all [webkit](http://www.webkit.org/) based browsers.

Unfortunately there has been no response from the Chromium development. I suggest you vote for this issue on the link provided to help see it resolved in future revisions.

Comment: @Sven Ah ok, this is strange ill have a further look.

Comment: @sven I found the bug reported in the chromium issue log

Comment: Thx for clearing this out! I upvoted the question, not more that I can do for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround using jQuery.

```
$(your_slider).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0 ){
        $(this).scrollTop(0)
    }
});
```

If you are scrolling horizontally then replace scrollTop with scrollLeft

Answer (score 2):

if you change 'overflow' of HTML element to 'hidden' it stops it from scrolling. 
The only problem is with 'mousemove' event. If you disable scrolling (overflow=hidden) on mouse down it will work fine. If you do it on mouse move (e.g. for dragging) it won't work. 
So you should move disabling of scrolling from 'onmousemove' to 'onmousedown'.